# equivalent of .Find_first method for bitsets in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, bitset

The title pretty much summarizes it.

In gcc, you can use the `.Find_first()` method on a bitset to get the position of the first significant bit. Is there any equivalent in Visual Studio?

I know you can use `_BitScanForward64` in Visual Studio to get the first significant bit, but I work with bitsets of the size larger than 64, and this method only works with 64-bit integers.

I also am not interested in the De Bruijn bit twiddling method.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<size_t N>
size_t highbit( bitset<N> const& bs ) {
  auto str = bs.template to_string< char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >();
  size_t retval = 0;
  for(auto it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it, ++retval)
  {
    if (*it == '1')
      return retval;
  }
  return retval;
}
```

No bit twiddling, as requested.  Returns `N` if the bits are all zeros.

Personally, I would recommend bit twiddling instead.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to check the value of the bits individually, which is not what I had in mind when I asked the question. I am/was mainly interested in some compiler-dependent instructions like `fbs`.